# How can I put chess pieces(images) to my div tag?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I made a chessboard using JavaScript/TypeScript. I'm trying to add chess pieces to the starting positions and I have no idea how to do that. If someone can give me a heading it would be great!

```
for (let i=0; i< 64; i++){
    document.getElementById("ChessBoard").
    appendChild(document.createElement("div")).
    style.backgroundColor = parseInt((i / 8) + i) % 2 == 0 ? 'white' : 'black';    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bellwater99/4Ap4M/217/

Comment: Why do you have periods at the end of two of your statements?

Comment: they're suppose to be one long line but just thought it would look better in 3 lines.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.

Comment: As you're in a *for* loop, you should save "ChessBoard" on a variable outside and then use it inside the loop. Even your code work is common style that the *dot* is preceding the method or attribute name, and not to be stick at the end of the line.

Comment: You should create a div element for each piece with the exact size of a square in the box, and then position ever the proper square. You could set the image of the piece on the div background and use drag&drop events to allow moves.

Answer (score 1):

HTML characters for chess figures map from *`&#9812;`* to *`&#9823;`*

> ♔
>   ♕
>   ♖
>   ♗
>   ♘
>   ♙
>
> ♚
>   ♛
>   ♜
>   ♝
>   ♞
>   ♟

```js
//               W = 9812..9817;  B = 9818..9823       (- 9811 =)
// (EMPTY = 0)   W = 1..6;        B = 7..12

let board = document.getElementById("ChessBoard");
let map = [
  3, 5, 4, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3,
  6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,   
  12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,
  9,11,10, 8, 7,10,11, 9,
];

for (let i=0; i< 64; i++){
  let tile = document.createElement("div");
  tile.style.backgroundColor = parseInt((i / 8) + i) % 2 == 0 ? 'white' : 'lightgray';
  tile.innerHTML = !map[i] ? "" : "&#"+ (9811+map[i]) +";";
  board.appendChild(tile);
}
```

```css
#ChessBoard{
  width:420px;
  height:420px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
div{
  width:52px;
  height:52px;
  float:left;
  font-size:40px;
  line-height:52px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="ChessBoard"></div>
```

Using an Array for game`map` is also useful later when developing the actual game and keep reference on the current figures position.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
var rook = [0,7,56,63];
var knight = [1,6,57,62];
var bishop = [2,5,58,61];
var king = [3,59];
var queen = [4,60]
var pawn = [8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55];

for (let i=0; i< 64; i++){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    document.getElementById("ChessBoard").
    appendChild(div).
    style.backgroundColor = parseInt((i / 8) + i) % 2 == 0 ? 'white' : 'black';    
    div.innerHTML = i;
    if(rook.indexOf(i) !== -1){
        div.innerHTML = 'r';
    }
    if(knight.indexOf(i) !== -1){
        div.innerHTML = 'n';
    }
    if(bishop.indexOf(i) !== -1){
        div.innerHTML = 'b';
    }
    if(king.indexOf(i) !== -1){
        div.innerHTML = 'k';
    }
    if(queen.indexOf(i) !== -1){
        div.innerHTML = 'q';
    }
    if(pawn.indexOf(i) !== -1){
        div.innerHTML = 'p';
    }
}
```

We can set the innerhtml for each div based on the 'i' in your for loop. this could be expanded to have a case statement to append the img to the div based on it's 'i'.

Comment: I also found this reference for html codes for pieces: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_symbols_in_Unicode

Comment: how can i use the html unicode and add it as object or img or somewya to add it to the inner html?

Comment: div.innerHTML = '&#9812;' this would be a white king. The html codes are on that link I gave you. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah helped me out a lot! But, how do i make the pieces look better? What do i have to refer to in css to center the pieces and make i  bigger?

Comment: No problem, you can just use something like font-size on the div tag. heres a working example: http://codepen.io/nilestanner/pen/rLXyAg

Comment: When I try copying my jsfiddle and try compile it on typescript using terminal error pops up saying that property style doesn't exist on type node and argument of type number is not assignable to type string. How can if fix the errors although it works in jsfiddle?